# URLSearchParams not defined error Inside A Function

Tags: javascript

This is very odd, using DW CC 2018 (in case that is where the problem is), when i use `URLSearchParams` inside a script tag in my HTML page, it does not get flagged as an "error".

I put `URLSearchParams` in my external JS file, inside a function, it gets flagged as "not defined". DW flags it as an error, but it still works, so must be more of a "warning" than an error. This has me a bit concerned even if it is a warning, that it could break when going live.

Should I worry, or is it just once of those things to just ignore?

Comment: URLSearchParams isn't supported in all browsers, so I would assume different developer platforms would have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dreamweaver probably uses an outdated list of "expected globals" in its indexer that isn't updated to include the [`URLSearchParams` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), since it's relatively recent.

If you're not concerned with backwards compatibility **cough* IE *cough**, just add this somewhere in the offending file to get Dreamweaver to shut up:

```
const URLSearchParams = window.URLSearchParams;
```

If Dreamweaver doesn't support ES6 syntax (I've never used it), then you must add this somewhere that's not at the top level:

```
(function () {
  // must be in a closure
  var URLSearchParams = window.URLSearchParams;

  ...
})();
```

The reason why is because top-level `var` overwrites the global namespace in some browsers.

Comment: I am not too concerned about older IE, since I am going with Bootstrap 4, so I pulled that trigger on old IE. I did see something, and it got me confused, about JEST, and that ES needed to be 5 or greater. i will try the "let" statement and see what happens. Just odd that it is happy in HTML script tag, but not in a file.

Comment: I see you changed the "let" to "const". The Let did work, but also had to change the LINT setting in DW. DW gave me an error of Let needs esversion: 6, and here is a [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/linting-code.html) `LINK` on how to change it. it is quick and easy. Once I did that, "let" did work and cleared the error. But it still needed the "let" it threw the error, if i took it out.

Comment: @MaxThrust the only reason I changed it is because canonically, it's more correct to define the namespace of an API as `const` since the value is never expected to be overwritten with something else.

Answer (score 0):

you can write custom URLSearchParams class

```
class UrlSearchParams {
  constructor(query) {
    this.query = query;
  }
  getSearchObject = () => {
    const { query } = this;
    return query
    ? (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
      .split("&")
      .reduce((params, param) => {
        let [key, value] = param.split("=");
        params[key] = value
          ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, " "))
          : "";
        return params;
      }, {})
  : {};
  };
  getAll = () => {
    const searchParams = this.getSearchObject();
    return searchParams;
  }
  get = param => {
    const searchParams = this.getSearchObject();
    return searchParams[param];
  };
  setUrl = (param, value) => {
    const searchParams = this.getSearchObject();
    searchParams[param] = value;
    return Object.keys(searchParams)
    .map(key => key + "=" + searchParams[key])
    .join("&");
  };
}

export default UrlSearchParams;
```